# What is the shortest and the best approach to calling a complicated method in python?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I have an error when running this section codes:

```
def foo(a=1, b=None, unit=1, *arg):
    # some process    
    print(a + min(arg))

foo(arg=3,4)
```

`Out[0]: SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`

What is the best way for calling `.foo()` method?
I want get minimum of some numbers then added to **'a' value** as static.

**Note**: Assume `.foo()` has some static input variables.
**Note**: I expected `"4"` to be printed.

I know that we **can't** define `.foo()` method such as bellow:

```
def foo(*arg, a=1, b=None, unit=1):
    pass
```

And I don't want assign any value to static `.foo()` variables **(a, b, unit)**

Comment: But `arg=3` makes no sense, since `arg` is not a parameter. Furthermore you can not define unnamed arguments after parameters with default values. It is not only the call here that causes trouble, but the function definition as well.

Comment: foo (arg = (3, 4))

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge This not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the explicit and shortest approach to calling the `.foo()` method, which not required to assign value to static `.foo()` variables is like the following code:

```
def foo(a=1, b=None, unit=1, *arg):
    # some process    
    print(a + min(arg))

def co_foo(*arg):  # co function
    foo(1, None, 1, *arg)

co_foo(5,3,4)  # expected print(1+3)
```

`Out[0]: 4`

Or:

```
def foo(a=1, b=None, unit=1, *arg):
    # some process    
    print(a + min(arg))

def co_foo(*arg):  # co function
    foo(1, None, 1, *arg)

arg = [5, 3, 4]
co_foo(arg)  # expected print(1+3)
```

`Out[1]: 4`

In this approach we define a co-function to simple calling the `.foo()`

Comment: That's as close as you can get to what you want, taking foo and its param list as a given.

Answer (score -1):

*arg means the method takes variable length of argument based on the positional values.

The below example may throw a light on the concept!
Hope it helps!

```
>>> def foo(a=1, b=None, unit=1, *arg):
...     print(arg)
...     print(a+min(arg))
... 
>>> foo(*[1,2,3,5,6,7])
(5, 6, 7)
6
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want change any static foo input variable.

Comment: This isn't a C or C++ *. So it has nothing to do with call by reference and changing input vars. In Keerthana's example 1 is assigned to a, 2 is assigned to b, 3 is assigned to unit and [5, 6, 7] is assigned to arg (which would by the way be called args by most Python dev's). * unpacks a sequence into separate params at call time and packs a sequence into one param at definition time.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I know about that python start (pack/unpack) and C++ star (pointer), but in your approach you assign to a, b and unit a value, but I don't want it, I declare a,b,unit as statics. I want only assign some value to *arg.